# Are the methods in the <cstring> applicable for string class too?

Tags: c++, stl

I've tried out using `memcpy()` method to strings but was getting a "no matching function call" although it works perfectly when I use an array of `char[]`.
Can someone explain why?
[www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Comment: show us what you are trying to do

Comment: No, the functions in `<cstring>` are for C-strings, i.e. arrays of `char`. You might want to check out e.g. [this `std::string` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: `std::string` has a copy constructor and an `operator=` for copying.

Comment: @JoachimPileb and NathanOliver Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` is an object, not a contiguous array of bytes (which is what `memcpy` expects). `std::string` *is not* `char*`; `std::string` *contains*  `char*` (somewhere really deep).

Although you can pull out the `std::string` inner byte array by using `&str[0]` (see note), I strongly encourage you *not to*. Almost anything you need to do already is implemented as a `std::string` method. Including appending, subtracting, transforming and anything that makes sense with a text object.

So yes, you can do something as stupid as:

```
std::string str (100,0);
memcpy(&str[0],"hello world", 11);
```

but you *shouldn't*.

Even if you *do* need memcpy behaviuor, try to use `std::copy` instead.

Note: this is often done with C functions that expects some buffer, while the developer wants to maintain a RAII style in his code. So he or she produces `std::string` object but passes it as C string. But if you do clean C++ code you don't need to.

Comment: Even it normally is the same, `str.c_str()` or`str.data()` are a bit nicer than `&str[0]`... At least they are guaranteed to point a the beginning of a consecutive sequence of characters.

Comment: only that `c_str` and `data` returns const pointer which you can't write to, only read from.

Comment: Are you really sure you are allowed to safely write to `&str[0]`? It should work, but there could be corner cases...

Comment: it is ok, but dangerous which is exactly why you should not do it in 99.9% cases of the time. it may create a problem if the string is too small, for example. windows developers usually invoke this technic from time to time when winapi expects a buffer, like `MultiByteToWideChar` , for example.

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no matching function call. You're trying to use C library functions with C++ types.

Comment: memcpy is available in C that's right. But it does not mean it's a C library function only. there is a std::memcpy and memcpy(C style) variance of this functionality.

Comment: @DawidPi: No, it is still a C standard library function. C++ pulls C standard library functions into namespace `std`, but they are still C standard library functions and assuredly have no knowledge of C++ types like `std::string` whatsoever.